# Bootstrap Navigation Bar isnt working, menu keeps hiding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, bootswatch

I building a website using bootswatch for css. Few days ago everything was working fine and then i noticed that my menus suddenly disappeared from the nav bar. I have checked different sources and different like wise question however they dont relate to this. I am working with it on my PC. Here is the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mega Data Base</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaDB</a>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">        
         <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>lecturehalls/">Lecture Halls</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>teachers/">Teachers</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
           </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['university_name']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>users/logout">Log Out</a></li>

          <?php else: ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>users/login">Login </a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <?php Messages::display(); ?>
        <?php require($view);  ?>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Please any solutions as to what I need to do in order to make it appear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need adding **jquery.min.js** & **bootstrap.min.js**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MegaDB</a>
        </div>


        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">        
         <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>lecturehalls/">Lecture Halls</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>teachers/">Teachers</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
           </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['university_name']; ?></a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>users/logout">Log Out</a></li>

          <?php else: ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>users/login">Login </a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <?php Messages::display(); ?>
        <?php require($view);  ?>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those Script in head.Because Bootstrap Depends on Jquery and Bootstrap Js.
You are only Load Bootstrep css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```